# I need maven to give more detailed logs

Tags: java, angular, maven, gitlab, pipeline

we have an angular+java app which gets built with maven and I have been trying to decrease our gitlab pipeline duration

i was wondering if there is a way to have better logs

i have tried -e & -X switches in the command (mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -P prod)

im also open to suggestions about more detailed angular build log

Comment: What is your actual goal?

Comment: decreasing angular build time in our pipeline. And also the build downloads dependencies from our nexus repo

Comment: if you store both angular and java code in the same project there is no option to influence on that: compiling modern JS code is time consuming and the best option is to create dedicated project for angular and implement release management there.

Comment: In which way do you think: `And also the build downloads dependencies from our nexus repo` this can be reduced?

Comment: @khmarbaise well there is always caching but i see that as a last resort